# Accessing NotMapped Computed Properties Using BreezeJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I've followed the examples laid out in http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities, and the DocCode test labeled "unmapped property can be set by server class calculated property".

When I try and access the unmapped property, it has the same value as it did when it was set in the constructor.  I have verified that the server is returning the unmapped property.  It is possible that I don't know the proper way to access the unmapped property when using angularjs with breezejs.

See below on the two lines I've commented as "empty string, value expected".

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

var ms = new breeze.MetadataStore();

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    serviceName: 'breeze/Projects',
    metadataStore: ms
});

manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);
manager.fetchMetadata()
    .then(function () {
        var Sheet = function ()
        {
            this.previewUrl = "";
        }

        ms.registerEntityTypeCtor("Sheet", Sheet);

        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Project")
            .withParameters({ id: $stateParams.projectId });

        manager
            .executeQuery(query)
            .then(function (data)
            {
                var p = data.results[0]; // project
                var s = p.sheets[0];
                console.log(s["previewUrl"]); // empty string, value expected
                console.log(s.previewUrl);    // empty string, value expected
            })
            .fail(function (e)
            {
                console.log(e.message);
                alert(e);
            });
    });
```

**Edit: Additional Info**
I've figured out that this is caused by the camelCase naming convention.  I was able to fix the bug in breeze.js by altering the getPropertyFromServerRaw function to this:

```
function getPropertyFromServerRaw(rawEntity, dp) {
    return rawEntity[dp.nameOnServer || dp.isUnmapped && rawEntity.entityType.metadataStore.namingConvention.clientPropertyNameToServer(dp.name)];
}
```

Hopefully this fix can make it into the next version of breeze.js